# A Dynamic data as a input in a Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I want to get a `Dynamic` data type as input a function, and use it in the implementation of such function.
Suppose this function:

```
getA :: (Typeable b) => b -> IO ()
getA t = do
         let v = case fromDynamic t of
                   Nothing -> error "Nao Foi Possível Converter"
                   Just x -> x 
        putStrLn "Ok"
```

This error occurs:

```
Could not deduce (b ~ Dynamic)
from the context (Typeable b)
  bound by the type signature for getA :: Typeable b => b -> IO ()
```

If i change the signature of the function to `getA :: Dynamic -> IO ()`, so the error is:

```
No instance for (Typeable a0) arising from a use of `fromDynamic'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

What data type should i use in this case?

Furthermore, is it possible to call a function from a class that `x` is instance? Something like:

```
case fromDynamic t of
  Nothing -> error "Nao Foi Possível Converter"
  Just x -> putStrLn$ sayHello x
```

, where `sayHello` is a function of a class which `x` is instance.

Answer (score 6):

`getA :: Dynamic -> IO ()` is the right signature. But you actually need to *use* it for something! If you simply match `Just x -> x` then the compiler has no idea as what type you'd like to use this value.

```
 v = case fromDynamic t of
      Just x -> x + 5 :: Int
```

should work.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is actually telling you exactly what's wrong, the usage of "x" in the case match expression is ambiguous because your use "x" is completely polymorphic, the type checker can't deduce the value because it could be anything.

For instance if you wanted to print the extracted value out you'd expect the value to a be a `String` where the `putStrLn` statement would witness the constraint of `(x ~ String)` and compile properly.

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Dynamic

getA :: Dynamic -> IO ()
getA t = do
  case fromDynamic t of
    Nothing -> error "Nao Foi Possível Converter"
    Just (x :: String) -> putStrLn x
  putStrLn "Ok"
```